# ASP.NET MVC Visual studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc

¿Porqué ya no aparece la opción **change authentication** en la plantilla de proyecto Web ASP.NET Framework MVC en visual studio 2019?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, no lo veía, lo han cambiado de sitio con respecto a visual studio 2017. Está al lado derecho en la parte de arriba de las opciones de la siguiente manera:

**Authentication**

No Authenticantion

Change